# How to create a yaml file to use a predrawn 2d map in a .pgm format to execute on ROS for navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, yaml, pgm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey. I am trying to use a pre-drawn map made in .pgm format to allow my turtlebot to nagivate through it. I have the .pgm file but do not know how to convert that into YAML as I have only heard from some of my peers that YAML is used in ROS to navigate through a pre-existing known map. Can someone publish the procedure for the same please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256447/i-am-trying-to-create-a-yaml-file-to-use-a-predrawn-2d-map-in-a-.pgm-format-to-execute-on-ros-for-navigation.-can-someone-guide-me-about-the-procedure-to-create-this-yaml-file?/) by [rahul.pillai93](https://answers.ros.org/users/29614/rahul.pillai93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the ROS wiki, there the [YAML format](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format) of the `map_server` is documented.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1